# spring-ws WS-ReliableMessaging support

Tags: java, spring-ws, ws-reliablemessaging

I have a project that is used for testing web services and it uses spring-ws library. 
Will spring-ws support WS-ReliableMessaging in the *near* future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Spring-WS lead, I can tell you that implementing WS-ReliableMessaging is not on our radar.